# How to list directories that aren't being symbolic linked to in a directory?

Tags: unix, find, symbolic-link

I'm trying to do some cleanup similar to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/132388/list-all-symbolic-links-on-a-directory).  In a UNIX OS, I want to delete the directories that aren't being symbolic linked to in a given directory.

e.g. I have a deployment script that creates a directory structure for an app like this:

```
1.0-201103071711/
1.0-201103071718/
1.0-201103071729/
current -> /opt/myapps/fooapp/1.0-201103071729/
```

I want to create a script that will remove the directories in that directory that aren't the "current" directory.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Bash snippet will find directories that have no directories linked to them. It will also find broken links.

```
for f in *; do (($(find -L -maxdepth 1 -samefile "$f" 2>/dev/null | wc -l) == 1)) && echo "found: $f"; done
```

It does not look outside the current directory or in subdirectories.

Be sure to test it thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

As the referenced question mentioned, there isn't an official way to do this.  As an alternative to Dennis' option, I present the following horrible hack.  Please be sure to test thoroughly as well.  I'd recommend replacing the `-exec` portion with an `ls` until you're sure it works.

`touch current;find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -mmin +2 -exec rm -rf {} \;`

It will check the current directory only.  It essentially touches the directory linked by 'current', and then removes anything with a modify time older than two minutes.  If the other directories haven't been touched in a while, you can increase the timer on `-mmin`, so you don't accidentally nuke the directory you want.  This is obviously only viable if you don't mind changing the timestamp on the current directory.


--Christopher Karel